# JFrame not presenting any Components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, components

I am using the following code to create a very simple `JFrame`, but  for some reason it doesn't show any components, just a blank frame. Why is this happening? I created frames a bunch of times and I just can't figure out what is wrong. The code is:

```
Main(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Colorizer | By: NonameSL");
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setContentPane(panel);
    textField=new JTextField("Enter your name!");
    textField.setBounds(0,0,40,200);
    textField.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    button=new JButton("Go!");
    button.setBounds(0, 200, 40, 200);
    button.setVisible(true);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    rectangle=new RecShape(Color.WHITE);
    rectangle.setBounds(0,40,400,160);
    rectangle.setVisible(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(rectangle);
    Main.frame=frame;
    registerButton();
}
```

The `RecShape` class is a class I created to simply create a rectangle shape on screen.
What is wrong?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead [use layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Comment: Btw, never call `setBounds/setSize/setLocation` Leave all that to LayoutManager's, its their job, not yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put  `frame.setVisible(true);` *after adding components to* `JFrame`, and it will show all the added components. Moreover, you should use specific layout rather than setting bounds for components. You can use a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I tried to figure out what's wrong with my code for hours, I guess I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to move `frame.setVisible(true);` to the end of the method; the visibility must be set to true after you have added the components.

Alternatively, you can add the following to the end of your method:

```
frame.revalidate();
frame.repaint();
```

to revalidate and repaint the frame with the newly added components although I recommend the former method.

Comment: Though the line `frame.revalidate()` will work on `1.7+`, in the previous versions, you have to use `frame.getContentPane().validate()` I guess

Answer (score 1):

you can add this at the end;

```
frame.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

Better your first add components to your variable "panel" and add then your finished panel to the `.getContentPane().add()`.

And the most important issue is that you better call `frame.setVisible(true);` at the end of your method.

Comment: "As a convenience `add` and its variants, `remove` and `setLayout` have been overridden to forward to the `contentPane` as necessary."—[`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Comment: Correct; the original formulation is still seen in some tutorials.